# The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

When I deploy my .NET application (targeting .NET framework 4.5) on IIS I am getting the following error message:

> Parser Error Message: The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, `<compilation targetFramework="4.0">`). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.

I have tried many solutions, like set the Aplication Pool to run under .NET 4, enable directory browsing, restart IIS and so on, but still receive the same error.

When I deploy the same application on another server with the same IIS setting it works fine. The IIS version on both servers are 7.5.7600.16385.

What am I missing on this server?

Comment: It seems that .Net 4.5 isn't installed on problem server. You should check installed versions [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: See duplicate and @Dima's remark, you just need to install the proper .NET Framework version on your server. What specific version depends on what is actually in your `<targetFramework="?.?" />` tag.

Comment: thanks now its working after installation of .net framework 4.5