# ASP.NET the targetframework attribute is not allowed

Tags: asp.net, web-config, httpruntime, target-framework

I have these lines in my web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5120000" executionTimeout="54000" requestValidationMode="2.0" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
```

But on the `httpRuntime` element I get the design time error `the targetframework attribute is not allowed`

The strange thing is that this occurs on my local development machine and other sites on it work fine with these definitions in their respective web.config files. All sites are using the same application pool. ASP.NET4.5 is installed (I double checked using the Microsoft Web Installer tool)

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143777/asp-net-mcv4-framework-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498745/the-targetframework-attribute-currently-references-a-version-that-is-later-tha) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890245/how-to-add-asp-net-4-0-as-application-pool-on-iis-7-windows-7/4890368#4890368) already

All other posts recommend installing ASP.NET4.5 on the server, but that has been done by me already. What else can I check?

Comment: Any difference in Visual studio version in local dev machine for this particular project? Just curious coz' targetframework is an attribute of httpRuntime tag in 2012 and above

Comment: Nope, I run them both in Visual Studio 2013 Express. Can I maybe also configure the target framework elsewhere in a website project besides from web.config and that may cause a conflict? (I'm guessing here)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? @Flo